# Sequence ID numbers in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a sequence number added to similar values:
In the same column:

`1DR` I am trying to number `1DR001`

```
1CP = 1CP001
1CP = 1CP002
1DF = 1DF001 
1DR = 1DR002
```

Comment: How "similar" do the values have to be before they'll be counted as part of the same sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if I understand correctly -

Let's say Column E looks like this -

```
1CP
1CP
1DF
1DR
```

In `F1` you type "001" and change the format of the column to "000"

In `F2` you use `=IF(E2=E1,F1+1,1)` and drag it on down to get your numbers.

Now, in `G1` you combine them - `=E1&TEXT(F1,"000")` and drag it down.

[image]